# Extracting only numbers from a string field in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I have a super simple problem in Hive. I've written the below extract, which should return '10' from the string. It works when I test it on regexr, but in Hive, it's just returning a blank field.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('DOM_10GB_mth','/[0-9]*/g', 0)
```

Comment: Replace `'/[0-9]*/g'` with `'[0-9]+'`

Comment: Amazing that worked! Why does it work in regexr but not in Hive though, any ideas?

Comment: The `/` are regex delimiters, they are not part of a regex pattern. `g` is a flag, not a part of the pattern either. You should only pass a *pattern* to the Hive function. At regexr, `[0-9]+` works, not `/[0-9]*/g` (as a pattern, it does not "work" there either)

Comment: Thanks - if you can make it an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function expects a regex *pattern* as the second argument. The `/` chars at online regex testers denote *regex delimiters* that are not part of regex *patterns*. The `g` part is a regex *flag* (to match multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string), and it is not a part of the pattern either. You should only pass a *string pattern* to the Hive regex function.

Also, to extract one or more digits, you can use `[0-9]+` rather than `[0-9]*`, as `*` matches 0 or more occurrences only.

Use

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('DOM_10GB_mth','[0-9]+', 0)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KSJwlb/2).

Note that at regexr or any other online regex tester, the `/[0-9]*/g` *pattern* [would not work either](https://regex101.com/r/KSJwlb/1).

Comment: See that this regexp will extract the *first* number from the string.  If your string is "AA10BB20CC" it won't return 1020, but just 10.

Comment: @neves Correct. The question is about extracting a single streak of digits from a string. The tile is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the numbers in a string, you must remove everything that isn't a number. Use this function to get it:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('DOM_10GB_mth','[^0-9]+', "")
```

@Wiktor_Stribiżew's answer would return just the first sequence of digits, so if you try to get the numbers from "111Z222" it would return "111". My answer will return "111222".